# Подключение к БД с удаленного ПК через интернет (JAVA)

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

На одном ноутбуке установлена СУБД postgresql. На втором ноутбуке - java приложение, которым пытаюсь подключиться к бд. Перекопал гугл, у людей были подобные проблемы, они их решали. Я пробовал указанные способы - не получается.

В качестве url указываю "jdbc:postgresql://**.**.***.***:5432/nameDB";

вместо **.**.***.*** - пробовал подставлять внешний ip, который определяется любыл сайтом из гугла, также пробовал подставлять IPv4 - результат один:

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Нового пользователя для БД создавал - без толку. Я чего-то не понимаю, а что именно - не знаю. Поскажите в чем может быть проблема и что можно почитать, чтоб разобраться с этим. Для дурака.

Comment: Между ноутами связь хоть есть? Пингуются?..

Comment: они находятся в разных сетках? если да, то там где ноут с базой и есть роутер то нужно пробросить в нем порт.

Comment: пробросил 5432 порт в роутере. в качестве ip указал IPv4 ноута с бд. результат тот же самый

Answer (score 1):

На ноуте с базой добавил порт в исключения брандмауера и в файле конфигурации субд разрешил подключения по сети и все заработало на ура